# Add to Path Visual Studio Release Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, environment-variables

**Background**: 
I have a program that links to a third party library. There are two versions of the library, so I have created two solutions that point to the same code. This may seem odd, but the code doesn't have to be different. Only the settings within the solution need to be different (i.e. library names are different and the CRT version is different).

- SolutionA uses versionA of the third party library (uses CRT version 8.0).
- SolutionB uses versionB of the third party library (uses CRT version 9.0).
- Both SolutionA and SolutionB point to the same code.

I have set up a Macro in the Project Property Sheets that points to the correct version of the library. The library files are not located within the solution folders. This Macro allows the projects to build correctly.

In order to get the executable to run, I have to tell it where the third party libraries are located. In order to do this, I can go to `Configuration Properties`-> `Debugging` -> `Environment` and add the path to the libraries to the `%PATH%` environment variable.

**Question**:
This works fine but is limited to debug mode. How can I add to the `%PATH%` environment variable in release mode? Can this be done using Project Property Sheets?

---

**Notes**: When the program is deployed, a batch file sets up the environment before it runs. However, I would like to be able to run the release executable within Visual Studio to keep things consistent (it would be easier for other developers).

Someone will probably ask why I don't have the libraries in the solution folders or why I don't throw them in with the executable. I hesitant to do so because one version of the libraries takes up about 180 MB. I only need two versions right now, but that is sure to change.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your problem but I tried to answer;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create separate solutions with separate properties. For one solution, you can create several configuration. Each configuration have its own compile parameters.

```
Right Click on your project -> Properties -> Configuration Manager -> New.
```

Regarding "This works fine but is limited to debug mode". Yes, you are setting parameters for Debug mode only. So this is normal it works in Debug mode only.

For you libraries, if they are static:

```
Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my main question, but will save me a lot of headache down the road! Creating new configurations will be *much* easier.

Answer (score 1):

The way we've gotten around this problem is to run visual studio itself using a batch file which sets up any environment variables (e.g., PATH) prior to the start of Visual Studio which inherits the environment. This allows for the environment settings to be temporary to the run of VS and inherited across all build configurations.

This works for Debug, Release, and any custom build configurations you may have.

Comment: Neat. And you are talking about launching the Visual Studio GUI or command line interface? Or does it matter?